# Proper way to reflect data changes in JFace viewers

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, jface

I am looking into `JFace` for Eclipse development. I made a plugin to act as a *dummy* content provider for a `ComboViewer`. This provider essentially provides the data model as an `ArrayList` of hardcoded values. Anyway, I tried to understand the approach.

I set the model on the `ComboViewer` via the `comboViewer.setInput(list)` method.
On the press of a button I call another object's method that updates the `list` I passed as `input` to the `ComboViewer` (adds another element) and I call `comboViewer.refresh` to reflect the change, but nothing happens.

**Turns out:**

I need to call `comboViewer.setInput(list)` *with the updated list* to see the changes in the data (i.e. the previous addition) in my UI combo. I found that `comboViewer.refresh` reflects any updates only if I get the a hold of `comboViewer`'s passed as input `Object` and modify that. I.e. if I do:

```
List<SomeObject> data = ((List<SomeObject>)(comboViewer.getInput()));  
data.add(new SomeObject("aaa","cccc"));  
comboViewer.refresh();
```

Only like this the data are refreshed. But I don't understand what is the proper way to use these APIs.
Am I supposed to ever get a hold and modify the object I pass in the `setInput` method? It feels I should not be doing it. So what is the purpose of `refresh`?

What is the proper way to do updates of the data that are provided to the `Viewer`s?

Comment: What is this `list`? All are updates fine without `setInput`.

Comment: The `list` is a list of custom objects with hardcoded values that are used as data of the `comboViewer`.Not sure what you mean `All are updates fine without setInput.`

Comment: Ok, I will provide you with some working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to reflect changes is to call `refresh`. The `list`

```
String[] values = {"1","2","3"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
```

create components

```
final ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
comboViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
comboViewer.setInput(list);
Button button1 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
button1.setText("Button 5");
button1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){

  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Button 5");
     list.add("4");
     comboViewer.refresh();             
  }

  @Override
  public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
  }

});
```

when you push the button the combo viewer is updated.

Comment: So you are saying that we can **share** the list with the `Viewer`?And updates on the list are reflected directly?So there is no issue with concurrency here?

Comment: Not directly but when you call `refresh`. As soon as the component only reads the data it could be used concurrently.

Comment: One last question.I am starter in `JFaces`.What is the recommended way to update UI?Like this or by something I read as databinding?I am asking to see what should I study next

Comment: databinding just simplify the view, better to learn at the source code, starting from `IStructuredContentProvider`. There's plenty of snippets on the site.

Comment: I am asking so that I don't follow wrong path.So if I start making stuff without using databinding, it is not considered bad?I am trying to figure out best practices and recommendations to adapt my learning steps

Comment: If you talk about `org.eclipse.core.databinding` it's a good point, http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.doc.user/html/features/swt/data_binding/example.html SWT/JFace Tutorial. But it's good as you understand the content providers.

Comment: If I use a `IStructuredContentProvider` as in the example here,if the `list` (let's take the OP) is updated by a background thread, how can this background thread "notify" the `ComboViewer` to call `refresh`?In the OP this code runs when I press a `Button` inside the class I associated with my part, so I already have a reference of the `comboViewer` inside the button's `selectedAction`.But from my background thread, I would not have such a reference to call `refresh`.How is this solved?Do you have an example for me to show?